# question this.props.onSave is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have problem is that action save not_function

handle save :

```
handleSave = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    const { category } = this.state
    this.props.onSave(category)
  }
```

action save :

```
 <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSave}>Save</button>
```

do you have a solution :

Comment: Youve not told us what the problem *is* that you want a solution for

Comment: _this.props.onSave is not a function

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It should contain whole components, not pieces of them you consider important. It's unknown where `this.props.onSave` comes from and why you expect it to be a function.

Comment: It's likely they aren't passing the `onSave` prop to the component containing this button (eg: `<OuterComponent onSave={(category) => {// some callback}} />`) but without seeing more code, I cannot be sure.

Comment: where is `onSave` prop comes from? Seems like you have a problem in your parent component when passing a `onSave` props.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because of missing binding in your constructor.
check if the handleSave method is bind in the constructor

Comment: Not quite. The code IS accessing the `handleSave` method and complaining about `this.props.onSave`.